# Using df.loc[] and In

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do the following code :

```
df.loc[df['Column'] in list]=1
df.loc[df['Column'] not in list]=2
```

But I have the famous error

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

So from what I understood from this error I already got, it is linked with the logic. What I want to know is Is there a specific typo to do what I am trying to do with a list, or do I have to expand my entire list like that (which in my case would be pretty ugly and long) :

```
df.loc[df[('Column']=='a') & (df['Column']=='b')]=1
df.loc[df[('Column']!='a') & (df['Column']!='b')]=2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `np.where`.  However, you need a column name.

```
df['new_column'] = np.where(df['Column'].isin(lst), 1, 2)
```

Consider the list `lst` and dataframe `df`

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Column=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Then

```
df['new_column'] = np.where(df['Column'].isin(lst), 1, 2)

print(df)

   Column  new_column
0       0           2
1       1           1
2       2           1
3       3           1
4       4           2
```

Comment: So the typo is shorter, how about the perf ? because I am doing a lot of these operations on a 140k line df

Comment: @Mayeulsgc performance relative to what?  Your chosen answer isn't even a complete answer.  However, `np.where` is generally very fast.  If I had a viable alternative solution, I'd show you a proper comparison.  Also, It's more beneficial for future readers to select an answer that solves your problem.

Comment: the solution I chose so far is working for me, performance time based

Comment: @Mayeulsgc - I think `np.where`  is much faster if compare with `df.loc[df['Column'].isin(list)] = 1` and `df.loc[~df['Column'].isin(list)] = 1`, so this answer is better.

Comment: ok, is it possible to have a variable value in spot of the 1 ? `df['new_column'] = np.where(df['Column'].isin(lst), 1, 2)` I would like to several values if the article is in the list, depending which item of the list it matched

Comment: @Mayeulsgc yes, that is possible.  You should be more specific.  Maybe even ask a new question.

Comment: ok, i'll stay with the isin until tomorrow, i can't accept another question before tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

The function you are looking for is

```
df.loc[df['Column'].isin(list)] = 1
```

Comment: is it possible to have it in a negative way ?

Comment: sure. Just use df.loc[~df['Column'].isin(list)] = 1. The ~ can be used as not

Comment: ah alright thx, i Tried the ! notation that didn't work, too much java

Comment: No problem. Numpy and pandas use ~ as not and | as or. Please mark my answer as the accepted answer if it solved the issue.